# Where I can find proper guidance to create Add-in for Revit using C#?

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit-2015

i have been assigned with a task to create an Add-In for auto desk applications.  Please guide me where can i learn to create the add-in, because i am new to auto desk applications.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read [ask], StackOverflow is for help with existing programming problems

Comment: You have to show your efforts trying to solve this task. SO is not a "we will write your code for you" site. If you then have specific questions on your code, you can come back and the community tries to help you.

Comment: @croxy read the description properly I am not asking for code, I just changed the title but you should have read the descrption too. previously I created the title 'how to create....' because i wanted it to be easy to the developers who are searching for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first port of call should definitely be the official Revit Developer Centre:

http://www.autodesk.com/developrevit

Work through the DevTV and My First Revit Plugin tutorials. That will provide all you need.

The Building Coder provides a comprehensive overview of the Revit API getting started material for self-learning:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#2

Comment: Thank you for posting answer on my question, at present  i am using the building coder and its really helpful for me and every new learner. i am so pleased that you posted on my question. Can you please suggest me the chapter where i can learn to export Revit design in other formats (i.e. 3D pdf ) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Revit does have PDF, but DWF is best for engineering files.

You can check the ImportExport sample, [first download the SDK](http://www.autodesk.com/developrevit) then check the **C:\Revit 2016 SDK\Samples\ImportExport\CS** folder. Ideally the DWF export will work best.

There are also some alternatives, like [A360 Viewer](https://360.autodesk.com/viewer).

Answer (score 0):

Here on the following link i got the basic training on how to create your first plug-in for Revit. and its useful for both Revit users as well as Developers.

http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=16459234